# How to access a Client from the ClientClaims?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, identityserver4

I want to access the Client from ClientClaims based on some of the claims using Entity Framework.

For example I have a Claim `{Type: Org, Value: 6 }` for multiple clients.

And I want all clients with this claim.

This is the entity:

```
namespace IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities
{
    public class ClientClaim
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It doesn't have ClientID and the Client property is not virtual therefore Entity Framework can't fill up the data and it comes as `null`.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Which version of the 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework' package are you using?

Comment: Latest. Currently it's 2.1.1